# Why does the value attribute render an input as read only and defaultValue render it as read-write?

Tags: html, reactjs

So I have a cart in which the quantity of the items added are dynamically incremented by +1 every time you add the same item, and within the cart itself the quantity of an added item can be manually changed by any preferred user number.

If I use the `value=""` attribute in the input field, the value is dynamically updated correctly, but then doesn't allow me to manually change the value. And if I use `defaultValue=""` the value does not update correctly every time an item is added, but allows me to manually chnage the value as required.

How can I both show the dynamic value correctly and be able to update the value field as required? My code is as follows:

```html
class CartItem2 extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    handleChange = e => {
      const { name, type, value } = e.target;
      const val = type === 'number' ? parseFloat(value) : value;
      this.setState(() => { return { [name]: val }});
    };
    updateCartItem = async (e, updateCartItemMutation) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log('Updating Cart Item!!');
      console.log(this.state);
      const res = await updateCartItemMutation({
        variables: {
          id: this.props.cartItem.id,
          quantity: this.state.quantity,
        },
      });
      console.log('Updated!!');
    };
    static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState){
        if (nextProps.cartItem.quantity !== prevState.quantity) {
            console.log("nextProps ", nextProps);
            console.log("prevState", prevState);
            return {quantity: nextProps.cartItem.quantity};
        }
        else return null;
    }

    render() {
        const { cartItem, client } = this.props;
        const { quantity } = this.state;

        return (
            <CartItemStyles>
                <img width="100" src={cartItem.item.image} alt={cartItem.item.title} />
                <div className="cart-item-details">
                <h3>{cartItem.item.title}</h3>
                <p>
                    {formatMoney(cartItem.item.price * cartItem.quantity)}
                    {' - '}
                    <em>
                        {cartItem.quantity} &times; {formatMoney(cartItem.item.price)} each
                    </em>
                </p>
                <Mutation 
                    mutation={UPDATE_CART_ITEM_MUTATION} 
                    variables={this.state}
                >
                    {(updateCartItem, { loading, error }) => {
                    return (
                        <Form2 key={cartItem.id} onSubmit={e => this.updateCartItem(e, updateCartItem)}>
                        <Error error={error} />
                        <label htmlFor="quantity">
                        <input
                            type="number"
                            id="quantity"
                            name="quantity"
                            placeholder="Quantity"
                            required
                            value={quantity}
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                        />
                        </label>
                        <button type="submit">Updat{loading ? 'ing' : 'e'}</button>
                        </Form2>
                    )
                    }}
                </Mutation>
                </div>
            <RemoveFromCart id={cartItem.id} />
          </CartItemStyles>
        );
    }
}
```

If you go here: flamingo-next-production.herokuapp.com, login using testing123@123.com and testing123, then click shop, then click cart, then add to cart multiples of the same item, then go to the cart and try and manually alter the item value.

Comment: Could you please share the implementation of `handleChange` ?

Comment: Also `carItem` is not defined in the snippet, right ?

Comment: Can we see your `this.handleChange` function ?

Comment: @Kabbany @Treycos I have amended my question to show `handleChange`. in regards to cartItem, that is passed in as a prop `const { cartItem, client } = this.props`

Comment: Is `carItem` a state or a props ?

Comment: @Kabbany `cartItem` is a prop.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are making a controlled input with a default value from the state? If so, you would need to set the initial quantity in the state to the `cartItem.quantity` value.

A lot of references are missing from below, but you should get the idea.

```
class CartItem extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      quantity: props.cartItem.quantity,
    };
  }


  handleChange = e => {
    const { name, type, value } = e.target;
    const val = type === 'number' ? parseFloat(value) : value;

    this.setState({ [name]: val });
  };

  render() {
    const { quantity } = this.state;

    return (
      <Mutation
        mutation={UPDATE_CART_ITEM_MUTATION}
        variables={this.state}
      >
        {(updateCartItem, { loading, error }) => {
          return (
            <Form2 onSubmit={e => this.updateCartItem(e, updateCartItem)}>
              <Error error={error} />
              <label htmlFor="quantity">
                <input
                  type="number"
                  id="quantity"
                  name="quantity"
                  placeholder="Quantity"
                  value={quantity}
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                  required
                />
              </label>
              <button type="submit">Updat{loading ? 'ing' : 'e'}</button>
            </Form2>
          )
        }}
      </Mutation>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: The current quantity value is correctly displayed when `value=` is used, but if I attempt to manually change the value of the input field to something different afterwards, I can't. The field remains read-only. So I've added an item 5 times, and the input field displays 5, if I attempt to change 5 to any other value it won't let me

Comment: That makes me think that the quantity value in your state isn't being updated properly. Are you using the quantity from your state in the value prop?

Comment: If you go here: `https://flamingo-next-production.herokuapp.com` and login using `testing123@123.com` and `testing123`, then click `shop`, then click click open the cart, then `add to cart` an item, then add that same item again, then go into the cart and try and manually alter the value displayed.

Comment: Yes, if you inspect the state and props you will see that the state is actually updating. I also see that you are still using the `quantity` from the `cartItem` prop.

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution does not resolve my issue. I have amended my original question with the full code. Everything functions perfectly, the field will just not come out of read-only mode and thus does not allow me to manually update it with a new value.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are passing a value from props `carItem` to defaultValue but onChange you are changing the state which is not passed to defaultValue.

To fix this you need to pass the state to defaultValue OR update the prop `carItem` in onChange

Comment: The first issue is that defaultValue only gets set on initial load for a form. After that, it won't get "naturally" updated because the intent was only to set an initial default value. The state is being correctly passed to `value`, as can be seen dev console, but no matter what I do the field is uneditable, as in it stays read only. If you go here: https://flamingo-next-production.herokuapp.com, login using testing123@123.com and testing123, then click shop, then click click cart, then add to cart multiples of the same item an item, then g to the cart and try and manually alter the item value

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by removing `static getDerivedStateFromProps()` and replacing with:

```html
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if (this.props.cartItem.quantity !== prevProps.cartItem.quantity) {
            let quantity = this.props.cartItem.quantity;
            this.setState(() => {
                return {
                    quantity
                }}
            );
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        let quantity = this.props.cartItem.quantity;
        this.setState(() => { 
            return {
                quantity
            }}
        );       
    }
```